# Persisting ManyToOne/OneToOne relations in Axon aggregate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, axon

Cascade types don't seem to work with the entity manager that axon uses. If I use CascadeType.Persist, the second time I try to create an object with the same child I get a duplicate key constraint error. If I use CascadeType.Merge, it won't work if the entries do not exist in the database.

Tried using different CascadeTypes, also the hibernate @Cascade annotations but with no avail. Also tried to use @AggregateMember for the children but the children entities don't seem to be saved before the parent.

```
@Bean
Repository<OfficialRecordEntity> axonOfficialRecordRepository(EntityManagerProvider emp, ParameterResolverFactory parameterResolverFactory, EventBus eventBus) {
        return GenericJpaRepository.builder(OfficialRecordEntity.class)
                .parameterResolverFactory(parameterResolverFactory)
                .entityManagerProvider(emp)
                .eventBus(eventBus)
                .build();
}
```

```
@Aggregate
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = {"id"}, callSuper = false)
@Builder
public class OfficialRecordEntity {
    @Id
    @AggregateIdentifier
    private String id;

    //many other fields

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private List<Accessory> accessories;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private ExpeditionType expeditionType;

    //many other commandhandlers/eventhandlers

    @CommandHandler
    public OfficialRecordEntity(CreateOfficialRecordCommand command) {
        apply(new CreateOfficialRecordEvent(command.getId(), command.getOfficialRecordDTO()));
    }

    @EventSourcingHandler
    public void on(final CreateOfficialRecordEvent event) {
        //...some field initializations    
    }
}
```

Both Accessory and ExpeditionType are entities as well.

I am aware that we are not using the axon framework to it's full extent but by this point I'm just trying to get to save all the children entities before the OfficialRecordEntity properly - was expecting that the cascade type should suffice but due to axon's entity manager provider it doesn't seem to work that way.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, I would to point I am mostly in the habit of using the Event Sourced approach of storing and retrieving an Aggregate.
Nonetheless, I have build a state-stored approach as well, which did include an Aggregate Root with several Aggregate Members under it, in a collection.

The following versions are of interest in deducing whether you have a similar set up as I have:

- Java - 8
- Axon Framework - 4.1.1
- Spring Boot (and Starter Data JPA) - 2.0.5.RELEASE

Then, my Aggregate and Entity looked something like this:

```java
// Aggregate sample
@Entity
@Aggregate
class SomeAggregateRoot {

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "entityId")
    @AggregateMember
    private List<SomeEntity> entities = new ArrayList<>();

    // Some command and event handlers...
}


// Aggregate Member sample
@Entity
public class SomeEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private String id;

    @EntityId
    private String entityId;

    // Some command and event handlers...
}
```

This set up, **without** specifying the `SomeAggregateRoot` Repository myself, works correctly for me. I thus let the `axon-spring-boot-starter` dependency auto configure all the necessary Axon components.

I do know this isn't a direct answer to your question.
I am however unsure where the issue lies in your set up, so I hope cross referencing your set up with what I just shared will give you an "a ha!" moment.

---

**Update**

To test this out with a shareable Github repository, I have set up one which shows the above in working condition, which you can find [here](https://github.com/smcvb/state-stored-aggregate).

Comment: The cross referencing seems like a great idea, I'm going to give that a go. Thank you!

Comment: I tried to do this on a small project(also in my precise use case) but in both cases I get a Command resulted in Persistence exception, detached entity passed to persist when updating a child that is already in the database. It seems to me that once the child entity has an id, it won't do an update since the persist() method is called :(. How come you don't encounter the same problem? :O

Comment: In my sample project, I did use an H2 database, as I didn't really want to be bothered with actually storing the result. So, maybe it's something with the database you're using?

Comment: I have the exactly same issue with an H2 database. I created a quick project to try out your solution(or anything by this point). Could you please have a quick look? Maybe I'm doing something obviously wrong... https://github.com/Vlad-Olaru/axon-hibernate-tryout

Comment: So, I just had a quite extensive look, where the main exception I got was `org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to instantiate default tuplizer [org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer]`. A quick Google suggests that's an issue with missing constructors.
Added, I see you're using Lombok. This might just cause inconsistencies somewhere so I would first try to set this up without Lombok.
Lastly, I see you have a `Student` Aggregate Member which you add in your commands/events. I would strongly suggest against adding the domain model in your messages.

Comment: I don't have that error, also tried on a colleague's laptop to clone the project and run it and he doesn't encounter it. You probably don't have lombok plugin configured properly or something. The issue I am running into is "Command 'com.example.axon.domain.commands.CreateCourseCommand' resulted in javax.persistence.PersistenceException(org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.example.axon.model.Student)". I'll take a note to not use domain models in messages, thanks for the tip!

Comment: I guessed it was Lombok, which led me to remove it entirely from the clone of your repository. Even without Lombok I got the same situation however...so not sure what I did wrong there. Let me put up an update of a repository I will create with a state-stored aggregate.